# .net core 3.1 Cannot assign requested address

Tags: .net-core, .net-core-2.2, .net-core-3.1

I have some troubles with a tcp connection using .net core 3.1.
It works well with .net core 2.2 but I can't figure out why it doesn't with the newest framework.
I get an error :

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (99): Cannot assign requested address

Here's my code (same code for .net core 2.2 and .net core 3.1) and same parameter (ip & port).

```
private bool SetupServerSocket(){
   bool isOk = true;
   try {
      IPEndPoint myEndpoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(_parametres.HostIp), _port);
      _serverSocket = new Socket(myEndpoint.Address.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
      _serverSocket.Bind(myEndpoint);
      _serverSocket.Listen((int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections);
    }
    catch (Exception ex){
       _logger.LogCritical("SetupServerSocket exception: " + ex);
       isOk = false;
    }
   return isOk;
}
```

Comment: It should behave the same after dotnet core 2.1 but still you might want to check the [remarks here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler?view=netcore-3.1#remarks).

Comment: Also worth checking is the ```ErrorCode``` of the ```SocketException``` which might tell us more to investigate. [SocketException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socketexception?view=netcore-3.1#remarks), [ErrorCodes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2)

Comment: If you could just share what the problem was, it might help others in the future. Just saying.

Comment: Sure..from VS2019, I was executing the App using the "docker" mode (don't know the right term) instead of the app.

Comment: using  AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false); from [remarks above](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.socketshttphandler?view=netcore-3.1#remarks) solved the problem for me